# I have installed cvlib in python but still can't import it

Tags: python-3.x, cvlib

I installed miniconda and just created a conda environment:

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.5 anaconda
```

I am trying to:

```
import cvlib
```

But I am getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named cvlib
```

So I have tried to install using:

```
pip3 install cvlib
```

This seemed to work successfully, but then when I try to `import cvlib` I am still getting the `ImportError: No module named cvlib` error (I have retarted my terminal after the installation).

Is this a problem with my PYTHONPATH not containing the path to the directory that now contains cvlib? If so, how do I find where cvlib is saved so that I can add the path?

Comment: Are you checking the import within conda environment ? I think pip usually doesn't install inside conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the library is in your python directory. Otherwise, make a repl.it account, and install cvlib, and check the functions or the lib name. Maybe try searching a more advanced installation of cvlib.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "check if the library is in your python code"?

Comment: oops, typo, i meant to say your python directory. I'm sure its in your py directory in libs somewhere? it should be where all your packages are.

Comment: So I did `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` to find the pythong directory: `/home/me/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python`. But this is not a directory apparently. So how can I check? Thanks!

Comment: im not familiar with miniconda, but look for a directory like python3.6.1. **This should be where your compiler is**. otherwise, srry dunno how to help ;c

Comment: Hi! I think every compiler, interpreter and env has a lib folder. Look for one, and install cvlib there. I think then it should work. If it doesn't, I'd suggest a good read of the installation guide.

Answer (score 0):

it might have occurred due to the version of python you installed or due to the directory, you installed.

try uninstalling the current version of python and try installing an older version of python and install it in the directory as shown below:

C:\Users\Rajish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

also, select add the path to environment variables while installing

and after that install cvlib and all other required modules and packages

it worked for me.